# exceeded limit on youtube search api

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am scraping keyword based info from youtube and hit the exceeded limit today. What are the options that are available?

1. open multiple projects
2. is there a paid service that can manage these limits?
   [image]

Comment: You may well [apply for a quota extension](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) to Google.

Comment: i did now. dunno how much time it takes for Google to review it. Interim, i created another project and have 10k quota on different token. Is there a limit on how many tokens i can create and how many projects i can create. This seems to be a easier solution for now.